# Jquery - Add table row after specific classes

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a row to a table using :

```
        $('#host_files').find('.main').last('tr').after(row);
```

This works fine and the row is added after the last .main tr

However the table may contain entries with class `main` and /or entries with class `other`

I want add my row after any entries of either class.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: `$('#host_files').find('.main, .other').last('tr').after(row);`

Comment: that doesn't work for me. I don't get a row added.

Comment: @Tom Could you clarify the goal? If you want to add a row after any matched entries, why do you use `last` (which always matches only 1 element)?

Comment: I've got this working. My table may have entries that have the class `.main` and there may be some with class `.other`. There should always be `main` but there could also be `other` in the same table.  I've got this working by counting  the `other` class in if it's > 0 adding after `other` else adding after `main`

Answer (score 0):

You just try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/11/)..

I updated your fiddle with a small example how you could do that.

Html

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
  <table id="blacklistgrid">
    <tr id="Row1">
      <td class="space">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row2">
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="shade" name="shade" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="red" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="green" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add few more Rows!</button>
</br>
</br>
<button type="button" id="btnAddCol">Add new column</button>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Css

```
td {
  padding-right: 15px
}
.space {
  padding-right: 75px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
     var count = 3,
     first_row = $('#Row2');
     while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
   });
 });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I don't get a row added to my table.

Comment: Sorry how does this show adding a row after multiple classes ?